# Managing a massive IF statement in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an if statement that has over 100 different if's.

at the minute im using something similar to this...

```
$('select').on("change",function(){
    if(  $(this).val() === 'tennis' )  {
        $('.sport').val('raquet');
    }
    else if(  $(this).val() === 'soccer' )  {
        $('.sport').val('goal');
    }
    if(  $(this).val() === 'snooker' )  {
        $('.sport').val('cue');
    }
});
```

I want to build one for counties in the uk, so if a user selects 'london' in the dropdown, the next field is populated with the postcode for london.

My problem is however, I could build it as my above example, only it would be huge.

Is it possible to have some sort of xml file to do this? or would it be possible to put each county and its value into an object inside an array and target it this way?

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/4xQeX/

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The usual solution is to store your sport/object pairs as data, because it *is* data.

```
var tbl = {
    tennis: 'raquet',
    snooker: 'cue',
    ...
};
```

and then use this simple code :

```
$('select').on("change", function(){
    var t = tbl[$(this).val()];
    if (typeof t === "string") $('.sport').val(t);
});
```

---

You even could fetch `tbl` from a separate JSON file (or simply store it in another JS file) for easier management.

Supposing you want to use a separate JSON file, called `things.json`, then your file would be like this :

```
{
    "tennis": "raquet",
    "snooker":"cue",
    ...
}
```

And the code would be this :

```
var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (httpRequest.readyState === 4) {
        if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
            var tbl = JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText);
            $('select').on("change", function(){
                var t = tbl[$(this).val()];
                if (typeof t === "string") $('.sport').val(t);
            });
        }
    }
};
httpRequest.open('GET', 'things.json?time='+Date.now());
httpRequest.send();
```

Comment: At least use hasOwnProperty, `__lookupGetter__` or `__proto__` is a common name for sports

Comment: @Esailija: `hasOwnProperty` is sooooo slow (though it probably doesn't matter here). Alternatively one could replace `if (t)` with `if (typeof t === 'string')`.

Comment: Thanks @dystroy, makes perfect sense!

Comment: @FelixKling no it's not :)

Comment: @FelixKling it's not slow, IIRC you can call it like 10 million times per second

Comment: I just run my hash table benchmark and I got  6 million times per second for hasOwnProperty .http://jsfiddle.net/JT3W5/

Comment: @Esailija: I mean slow compared other property existence tests: http://jsperf.com/hasownproperty-vs-in/2. Granted, they are not strictly equivalent. It depends on the circumstances which one to choose. But since I know how `hasOwnProperty` performance, I rather avoid it.

Comment: @FelixKling Even if we ignore the fact that none of those are functionally equal to hasOwnProperty, the jsperf is totally unfair and irrelevant and I am working on a fix.

Comment: @Esailija: Don't know what's unfair, but I will wait for your fix :)

Comment: @FelixKling Here is preliminary test that already shows that misses are more expensive than hasOwnProperty. I still need to go through disassembly to figure out why the others are still unplausibly fast http://jsperf.com/hasownproperty-vs-in/3

Comment: @FelixKling btw I recommend you to come to http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript so we don't spam the comments

Comment: @FelixKling ok I finally nailed down the reason. The success functions were optimized under the assumption that the prop read always succeeds. Of course that is not the case in production, so I present you the realistic jsperf finally http://jsperf.com/hasownproperty-vs-in/3 :P (Only valid for V8)

Comment: @Esailija: I think I don't understand why whatever you did fixed it, but I will ask you about it when I have the time ;) Thanks for your effort!